# Show objects and references graphically in Python

Tags: python, debugging

I have objects which have an attribute containing a list of references to other objects (basically a network data structure). For debugging I'd like to see how objects are referenced.

Do you know a tool that can display this graphically?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/

Comment: Yes. Thanks!!! I didn't guess correct keywords for googling. Are there more alternatives? I believe once I saw one. But I try objgraph first :)

Comment: @Gerenuk you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer)

objgraph ( http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/ ) uses Graphviz to render graphs (as in networks, not plots) of Python objects. ([On PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph)). It works with Python 2 or 3. Its homepage has several examples of how to use it.

I don't know of any alternatives, but I haven't spent long looking.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was just looking for UML for Python and by accident I found what I had seen before. That looks similar: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/lumpy.html

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/nfergu/referrers.